# auth_views.password_reset keeps rendering the root url template, not the password reset one

Tags: django

**urls.py for my_app:**

```
urlpatterns = [

    # 4 inbuilt views for password reset:
    # - password_reset sends the mail
    # - password_reset_done shows a success message for the above
    # - password_reset_confirm checks the link the user clicked and prompts for a new password
    # - password_reset_complete shows a success message for the above
    url(r'^password-reset/$',
            auth_views.password_reset,
            {'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset.html',
             'email_template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_email.html',
             'subject_template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_subject.txt'},
            name="password_reset"),
    url(r'^password-reset/done/$',
            auth_views.password_reset_done,
            {'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_done.html'},
            name="password_reset_done"),
    url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
            auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
            {'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_confirm.html'},
            name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password-reset/complete/$',
            auth_views.password_reset_complete,
            {'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_complete.html'},
            name="password_reset_complete"),
    #url('^password-change/', auth_views.password_change,
    #    {'post_change_redirect':reverse_lazy('userlogout'), 'template_name':'accountmanagement.html'},
    #    name="passwordchange"),
]
```

**urls.py for project:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', LandingPage.as_view(), name="homepage"),
    url(r'^my_app/', include('my_app.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I visit `localhost:8000/my_app/password-reset/` I get my `landingpage.html` template instead. The dev server output definitely shows a single `GET` to `/my_app/password-reset/`, and I've checked all the project's apps' `urls.py`; the `password-reset` url isn't duplicated anywhere else.

I've even commented out that app's `TEMPLATES` directory in my settings file to try to force a `TemplateDoesNotExist`, and it does nothing - the password-reset view seems to be ignoring the `template_name` parameter that I pass in the url config file.

I'm stumped. What could cause this?

Comment: Please show the rest of your `urls.py`.

Comment: Done. It's pretty much https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views with custom parameters for the templates.

Comment: You need to show the *whole* file, especially the pattern for that landing page.

Comment: if it shows `landingpage.html` instead, then it means you have url configuration before password_reset which matches the regex. We need the line that uses `landingpage.html` and its position.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that someone else was working on the codebase. `reset_password.html` was supposed to `{% extends "landingpage.html" %}` but the frontend engineer rebuilt landingpage.html without the `{% block content %}` needed for it to be extendable, hence it just showed the landing page template.